# Gravitational Equipotentials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential

Can someone explain why the answer is B? I have flaws and inconsistencies within my knowledge.

In terms of how, it lies halfway between the two equipotential lines, so travels a distance of $r/2$, as potential difference between each equipotential is equal to V.

$$g = -v/r$$

So is that the reason it travels a distance of r/2? So $g$ increases by a factor of 2?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

Pretend this was a map, and the contour lines gave the heights of a hill.  Height here is analogous to (gravitational) potential.  The question is where is the greatest gravitational field strength, in other words which of these points is the steepest?  This is because gravitational field strength is related to the gradient of potential.  The steeper the decrease in $V$, the bigger the force.

So, since B is the place where the contour lines are closest to each other, B is also the place where the "hill" is the steepest, i.e. the gravitational field is strongest.

Comment: Yeah, like flux density, that is a good analogy